# How to fix import error 'nvcuda.dll' in spyder for python?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, spyder, dllimport

1.I already have nvcuda.dll in system32.

2.I have path C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.2\bin.

3.The program already upgraded tensorflow and GPU tensorflow.

I check import still have the error.

> ImportError: Could not find 'nvcuda.dll'. TensorFlow requires that
>   this DLL be installed in a directory that is named in your %PATH%
>   environment variable. Typically it is installed in
>   'C:\Windows\System32'. If it is not present, ensure that you have a
>   CUDA-capable GPU with the correct driver installed.

Why?
How to fix this problem shown by the message error ?

Comment: You've set the path for the binaries, but there's a different path for libraries. That must be set, too.

Comment: Where is path for libraries that I have to set? How to fix it? Sorry for I ask more, I'm just nursery beginner for codding and I never set up for tenserflow success.

Comment: Advanced system setting --->Environment variables that I have set it up but where is to set the libraries?

Answer (score 0):

As the comment mentioned, you need to ensure the time you import the tensorflow, the path environment points to `c:\windows\system32` and as you said you have `nvcuda.dll`, ensure the file is there too. There is no need to set the libraries.